# Confusion about bash parameter substitution

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script to rename a file or a series of files that contain a specific string

```
for i in "${@:3}"; do
        mv -- "$i" "${i/$1/$2}"
done
```

so when i do

```
bash script_name patter_1 pattern_2 string*
```

it does work but when i try:

```
mv -- "$i" "${i//$1/$2}"
```

it still works

```
${i/$1/$2}
```

and

```
${i//$1/$2}
```

so why is that happening, i search bash guide for beginner but still have no clue. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern
>   against its value is replaced with string. **If pattern begins with
>   ‘/’, all matches of pattern are replaced with string**

So if the replacement can be done just once, these are equivalent:

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
           ^
${parameter//pattern/string}
           ^^
```

See an example:

```
$ i="hello"
$ echo ${i/e/XX}  #just one replacement
hXXllo            # <----------------------
$ echo ${i//e/XX} # multiple replacements  | they are the same
hXXllo            # <----------------------
$ echo ${i/l/XX}  #just one replacement
heXXlo            # it just happens once!
$ echo ${i//l/XX} #multiple replacements
heXXXXo           # it happens many times!
```